# TextView setText and setVisibility not working in fragment

Tags: android, android-asynctask, settext

I have `ControllerFragment` which has 3 child fragments. Children fragments change are provided in the tabLayout via ViewPager. Unsend Apple and Banana badge count are computable variable values. `unSendAppleCountTxtView` and `unSendBananaCountTxtView` are changed according to these variable values.

My function is running main Thread.

Tried methods:

1. I have controlled null check and textView isn't null
2. `setUnSendAppleCount` function is taken in these threads (runOnUIThread, new Handler(), new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()))
3. I have tried `AsyncTask` and not working setView and setText in `postExecute` too.
4. And finally I scan all related questions and tried.

All methods didn't work. TextView is empty value.

```
public class ControllerFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.controller_fragment, viewGroup, false);

        tabs = ViewUtil.findById(rootView, R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = ViewUtil.findById(rootView, R.id.controllerViewPager);

        setFragments();
        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        setupTabIcons(viewGroup);

        return rootView;
      }

       private void setupTabIcons(ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        LinearLayout appleListTab = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(MyApplication.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tab_title_text_and_badge, viewGroup, false);
        RelativeLayout pearListTab = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(MyApplication.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tab_title_text, viewGroup, false);
        LinearLayout bananaListTab = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(MyApplication.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.tab_title_text_and_badge, viewGroup, false);

        unSendAppleCountTxtView = appleListTab.findViewById(R.id.badgeView);
        unSendBananaCountTxtView = bananaListTab.findViewById(R.id.badgeView);

        TextView appleTextView = appleListTab.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        TextView pearTextView = pearListTab.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        TextView bananaTextView = bananaListTab.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        setUnSendAppleCount(2);  //....this function is not working
        setUnSendBananaCount(2); //.....this function is not working

        bananaTextView.setText(getString(R.string.bananas));
        tabs.getTabAt(0).setCustomView(bananaListTab);

        appleTextView.setText(getString(R.string.apples));
        tabs.getTabAt(1).setCustomView(appleListTab);

        pearTextView.setText(getString(R.string.pears));
        tabs.getTabAt(2).setCustomView(pearListTab);
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

        TabsViewPagerAdapter adapter = new TabsViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFrag(bananaFragment, getString(R.string.bananas));
        adapter.addFrag(appleFragment, getString(R.string.apples));
        adapter.addFrag(pearFragment, getString(R.string.pears));
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    }

    private void setUnSendAppleCount(int unSendCount) {

        if (unSendAppleCountTxtView != null) {

         if (unSendCount > 0) {

         unSendAppleCountTxtView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         unSendAppleCountTxtView.setText(String.format(getMyLocale(), "%d", unSendCount));

         } else {
         unSendAppleCountTxtView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

controller_fragment xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/tab_unpressed_color">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/tabColor" />

        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/controllerViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar_layout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

tab_title_text_and_badge.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:background="@color/Black">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_weight="1.99"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/infoTitle"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/badgeView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start|center"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.01"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_controller_badge"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/miniTextSize"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:text="11"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Please help me

Comment: `setText does not working` showing wrong value?

Comment: no error in log. textview is empty vlaue

Comment: Probably because it is null, and you do nothing then... Remove the null check

Comment: Read about a [mcve]

Comment: May be unReadView is null or unReadCount value<=0

Comment: Have you verified that your `if` condition is getting executed ?

Comment: yes please can you see my edited answer

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but that's still not complete or verifiable. I'm pretty sure both setText and visibility work in a Fragment, but you're confusing it with all the other things in your Fragment, so your code is not minimal either

Comment: be sure please wait all of you:)

Comment: your unReadChatCountTxtView is null ! double check R.id.badgeView is valid?

Comment: no it is not null :(

Comment: My guess is that your `String.format()` doesn't work okay. Try to log that and see

Comment: no it is not working that remove String.format() so value is integer @IonutJ.Bejan

Comment: So, did you log that part ? Also, try `.setText(String.valueOf(unReadCount));`

Comment: Log.i(TAG , " unread count: " + String.format(getMyLocale(), "%d", unReadCount));

-> LOG : [TabControllerFragment]  unread count: 2

It is true @IonutJ.Bejan

Comment: Hmm, weird...try to add your `Fragment XML` also in your post.

Comment: yeap i shared its

Comment: I think I found your problem. `android:layout_weight="0.01"` this line, it is probably too less and it takes way less space for the text to be visible (even if you set only a number there) Put something like 1.5 for the other `TextView` and 0.5 for this ones with `android:textAllignment="center"`

Comment: is there any reason to use `tools:text` instead `android:text`?

Comment: only  tools:text provide that preview layout @Chithra

Comment: @IonutJ.Bejan it is not working, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess different thread problem. I have tried that eventBus for activity passing data to fragment and it solved.

```
  ControllerFragment(){

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

            if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)) EventBus.getDefault().register(this);

        }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
    }

   @Subscribe(sticky = true, threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
   public void onEventMain(ControllerEvent event) {

      if (event.getSelectedEventType() == ControllerEvent.tabControllerEventTypes.refreshCount.ordinal()) {

          setUnSendAppleCount(event.getAppleCount());

          }
      }
}
```

Comment: Accept answer and close question if you found an solution so others can find it answered.

Comment: If I accept my answer, stackoverflow write this alert : "You can accept your answer in 17 hours "

Comment: Wat do you mean? i didn't get you.

Comment: stackoverflow said that

Comment: Welcome.. ! Ok. Once accepted questions help others to find answered thats why i told. Happy coding.!

Answer (score 2):

try to setVisibility  `android:visibility="visible"` or  `android:visibility="invisible"` delete `gone` attribute it remove TextView.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/badgeView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start|center"
    android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.01"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_controller_badge"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/miniTextSize"
    android:visibility="visible" //change here
    tools:text="11"
    tools:visibility="visible" />
```

Comment: When app is opening at first time unReadCount = 0 so android:visibility="gone".
I tried inviisible but still not working,sorry :(

Comment: @propoLis try to set in else block visibility attr **invisible** like  else {
         unReadChatCountTxtView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
         }

Answer (score 2):

Please use `android:text` instead `tools:text`

1. tools:text="text" is used only for Android Studio layout preview (wont be visible while running the app)
2. android:text="text" is used to set text to a a layout element, which you can see when the app is run

Comment: only tools:text provide that preview layout and I remove tools:text like your wanted, but still not working

Comment: have you edited the visibility ?, i see there are two visibility mentioned `android:visibility` and `tools:visibility`. Also change the background color of the layout mentioned with `tools:background` because your `Textview` color is white on white background

Answer (score 2):

Try using the below xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/Black">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:layout_weight="1.99"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/infoTitle"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/badgeView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start|center"
    android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.01"
    android:background="@drawable/tab_controller_badge"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/miniTextSize"
    android:text="11"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: focus another thing not tools:D